# Kiel esperantigi la esperimon "O2O"

Tags: single-word-requests

O2O - Online to Offline

ĉu la esperimo "enrete ĝis derete" taŭgas? ĉu vi havas ion mallongan?

---

update: 28 Nov

O2O as in "According to Jon Carder, CEO of O2O network Empyr, whose mission is to bridge the gap between online and offline commerce, thinks the opportunity is a big one. "

Comment: Cxu vi povas diri frazon kun la esprimo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially unanswerable. A question about how to express a clearly defined idea would be better.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question, though the question should perhaps be expanded to include some context.

Comment: @JiriLebl Yes. This is very difficult question to answer without context. We need an example phrase.

Comment: "O2O" is a business initialism for strategies of drawing website customers (online) to physical stores (offline). It's also a terrible description and initialism.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Thanks, @vangelion. That's the O2O (online to offline) I meant. I didn't include the context as I thought it's a very familiar concept over the internet. Here's a report introducing O2O in China [link](http://www.innovationiseverywhere.com/o2o-why-china-leads-the-online-to-offline-revolution/)

Comment: A Google search shows that the acronym O2O is actually more often used in Chinese than in English. Perhaps that's why most people here aren't too familiar with that concept. If you're translating a text into Esperanto, you should probably add a sentence that explains what it means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laŭŝajne, *O2O, online-to-offline* estas kvazaŭ-anglalingva esprimo, uzata preskaŭ nur en Ĉinio, por fako de merkatiko. Ĝi aludas retan reklamadon kiu penas gvidi aĉetontojn al fizikaj butikoj. Evidente, tio estas tute ordinara praktiko tutmonde, sed la akronimo priskribas specon de reklama firmao kiu sin ĉefe okupas helpi butikojn konstrui ĉeestojn enrete.

Mi sugestas *eksterretiga* aŭ ***reto-al-butika***, kun ebla mallongigo *R-al-B*.

> *Laŭ Jon Carder, CEO de reto-al-butika firmaro Empyr, kies celo estas krei pontojn inter reta kaj eksterreta komerco, la situacio promesas multe.*

Comment: Koran dankon! reto-al-butiko estas multe plibona ol enrete-ĝis-derete, kaj la mallongigo R-al-B sajnas tre deca!

Answer (score 0):

Online to offline = **Elŝuti**

> Transmeti programon aŭ datumon el ĉefmemoro aŭ servilo al krommemoro
>   aŭ periferia komputilo, la malo de alŝuti: modernan Unikod-kapablan
>   foliumilon vi povas senpage elŝuti de Microsoft aŭ Netscape
>   http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sxut.html#sxut.el0i

Comment: Mi ege dankas vin pro via respondo. Sed elŝuti ne estas la vorton kiun mi serĉas. Bonvole legu la ekzemplan frazon kaj mian klarigon. Ĉu eblas havi vorton esprimi la signifon? :) :)